# R: replace with date in script

Tags: r

The idea is to get today's date, insert it into the code of the script as it runs.

Example:

```
date <- Sys.Date()

#Create directory with today's date.
if(!file.exists("../<date>")) dir.create("../<date>")
```

How to replace  with date object in the script? A function?

Comment: use file.path, `file.path('root', Sys.Date(), 'out')`

Comment: Thanks! This is solving it for everything I need.

Comment: @rawr add it as an answer?